# Plus sign in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a plus sign as shape, so here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:toDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%" >
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <solid android:color="#00000000" />
                <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#807DFF96" />
                <size android:width="50dp" android:height="50dp" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#807DFF96" />
            <size android:width="50dp" android:height="50dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

But it seems to be rendering only a line, based on which one I keep above.

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <rotate
      android:fromDegrees="90"
      android:toDegrees="0"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%" >
      <shape android:shape="line">
        <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#807DFF96" />
        <size android:width="50dp" android:height="50dp" />
      </shape>
    </rotate>

  </item>
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="line">
      <solid android:color="#00000000" />
      <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#807DFF96" />
      <size android:width="50dp" android:height="50dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Whenever you want to add multiple items use layer-list.